# How can I measure similarity between users who answer to the same questions

Tags: machine-learning, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

I am working on a project for recommending contents to the users. I want to create a profile from each user so that I can cluster them and offer common recommendations, but before I have to be able to measure similarity between these users. I have thought in a questionnaire which can be filled using fuzzy labels.

My question is How I can measure the correlation (similarity) for two users U1 and U2 who answer questions of this kind?

- **Q1.** I think that Tokyo is a nice city. **U1:** Fully agree  **U2:** Partially
  agree
- **Q2.** I have read Don Quixote. **U1:** Do not agree at all **U2:** Fully agree
- ...
- **Qn.** I think that Tarantino is a good film director. **U1:**
  Partially agree **U2:** Partially agree

I have thought to convert answers into numeric values and then try to compute Pearson correlation coefficient. But I wonder if there are more elegant ways to do that.

Answer (score 2):

It would be useful to convert the numeric values (from provided answers) into one single vector and then apply cosine similarity function. The cosine similarity has proven to be more reliable (and faster) than Pearson correlation coefficient.

Nevertheless, this is not a minor issue and the implementation could be very challenging.

Comment: Just converting the "Strongly agree" "partially agree" to a Likert scale (values in the range 1-4 or whatever they are) before doing vector similarity should be fine, I don't imagine it will be a challenging problem in and of itself. More likely is that the questions don't allow appropriate separation into clusters using any distance metric, I would have thought.